# Android listener for webpage to start loading?

Tags: java, android

I have a simple webview that loads a website.  Once the website is loaded, I have the following to focus/scroll to the login box:

```
mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mWebview.scrollTo(681, 100);
```

(I've heard that onPageFinished is deprecated, but it's working for me in 2.2>4.4, so I'm just leaving it for now.

Anyway, I would like some sort of way to monitor for when the user actually logs in, that way when the page is done loading for the second time, I can then call some js and forward them to another page, but I have no idea how to do that. :(

I can just do another onPageFinished after they log in, but I don't know how to start monitoring... In other words, I can't start another onPageFinished immediately after the current, because it just redirects automatically.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I would greatly appreciate it! :)

EDIT:

Here's the entirety (minus the import headers) of my MainActivity.java class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebview ;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebview.canGoBack() == true){
        mWebview.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mWebview  = new WebView(this);

    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
    mWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        mWebview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    }

    final Activity activity = this;

    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mWebview .loadUrl("http://example.com");
    setContentView(mWebview );


    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mWebview.scrollTo(681, 100);


        }
    }

    );



}
```

I think I might be missing a curly bracket, but ignore that for now, haha.  So anyway, after `mWebview.scrollTo` (the last line), the webpage is done loading, and it just chills at the login page.  After a user logs in, the page (obviously) starts to load and directs to another post-login URL.  I'd like to check the URL with an `if` statement after the page is done loading for the second time.

Does that make more sense?  Sorry, it's confusing me too, trying to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there will be two separate URLs, one for the post log-in page and one for the pre log-in page. You can have an `if` statement that checks the URL to make sure you've logged in, and if you have, then it redirects/closes/whatever.
I had a similar issue here:

[Closing a Webview in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24165440/closing-a-webview-in-android)

So basically you just want to execute some JavaScript once you've logged in? I don't see why you can't have an `if` statement to check whether you're logged in or not, and if you're logged in, then execute the js.
Something like this maybe?

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.contains(getString(R.string.loginURL))){
          super.onPageFinished(view, url);
          mWebview.scrollTo(681, 100);
         }else if(url.contains(getString(R.string.loggedInURL))) {
                wv.loadUrl(js goes here);
         }
    }
}
```

This will execute every time a page is finished loading in your `WebView`

Comment: I tried a few different versions of if statements, but the problem is, they load and parse the URL immediately after the page loads.  I need to find a way to "wait," if you will, until the new page starts to load before I can check the URL.  Does that make sense?  Sorry, I'm new to coding :p

Comment: I guess I'm confused by what you mean by monitoring. What do you mean? Can you show a little more code?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.  The `mWebview.scrollTo` is to focus the webpage on the login box.  The page stops loading, and the code is done executing.  From there, the user logs in, and the page loads to a new URL.  After it's done loading for the second time (post login, post `onPageFinished`, I want another onPageFinished, so I need to somehow monitor for the second refresh of the page.

Comment: I think as long as you don't close the `WebView`, `onPageFinished` will execute every time a page has finished loading. You might want to try putting it inside of a `WebViewClient`. I'll update above.

Comment: Hmm.  That's not working for some reason.  It's inside my `WebViewClient`, and it's not closed until after the loop.  :/